# VBA - SendKeys "Enter" Alternative for Mac Excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm attempting to run a macro in Excel containing the following VBA code:

```
Range("Results").ClearContents
For counter = 1 To 40
        Range("constant") = -0.04 + counter * 0.005
        Solve
        Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("constant")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("portfolio_sigma")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("portfolio_mean")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 4) = ActiveSheet.Range("x_1")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 5) = ActiveSheet.Range("x_2")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 6) = ActiveSheet.Range("x_3")
        Range("Results").Cells(counter, 7) = ActiveSheet.Range("x_4")
Next counter
```

at runtime, I receive an error stating that SendKeys isn't available on Excel for Mac. What is the most efficient alternative / workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you want the enter key to be pressed?

Comment: Yeah what is the "Enter" key actually hitting enter on after `Solve` ? A prompt box or moving cells or what?

Comment: What do you want to do, i.e. go down 40 rows?

Comment: So, when `Solve` is called, it uses the Excel Add-In **Solver** to read in input parameters for the Solver prompt and then commence the calculation. Once the calculation is complete, a summary dialog box appears which must be dismissed by clicking 'OK' or hitting 'Enter' on the keyboard. This is the reason for using `SendKeys` here. The ultimate aim is to perform this task 40 times, setting `constant` to a new value for each iteration, and print each set of resulting values as a separate line in a list on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use key press automation, then check out this post:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/436359-visual-basic-applications-sendkeys-mac.html

Comment: Thanks, but, as noted above, SendKeys does not work on Excel for Mac. In other words, even if I wanted to use it, I cannot. That is why I asked for "the most efficient alternative / workaround".

Comment: Sorry, the link is about a Mac equivalent of the SendKey function, you should check it out.